# Calculate second and third iterations

Tags: dynamical-systems

Let $$L_\mu(x) = \mu x(1-x)$$

Calculate $$L_\mu^2(x)$$ and $$L_\mu^3(x)$$

I understand how this works when given f(x) but I don't understand how to do this with mu in the function.

Comment: walk me through f(x) ?

Comment: Say you're given f(x) = 2x+1, then f^2(x) = f(f(x)) = 2(2x+1)+1 which is very straight forward - I'm confused about the mu in this question and how it affects the problem.

Comment: subscripts represent different than there normal functions ( sometimes for variable order like $\pi_{a,b}(n)$ being the prime counting function of numbers of form $ax+b$ less than $n$)

Comment: @Peach212: you are able to handle the constant $2$, but not the constant $\mu$ !?

Answer (score 3):

Note that, for every specific value $\mu$, the definition defines a function $L_{\mu}:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R.$ The notation $L_{\mu}^2$ is the second iterate of the function $L_{\mu}$ - that is,
$$L_{\mu}^2(x)=L_{\mu}(L_{\mu}(x))$$
where you are doing the same thing you would with $f^2$ except doing it to $L_{\mu}$ instead. So, for instance, you could get
$$L_{\mu}^2(x)=L_{\mu}(\mu x(1-x))=\mu[\mu x(1-x)](1-[\mu x(1-x)])$$
as one valid representation of this, where the bracketed expressions are just $L_{\mu}(x)$ - although you might reasonably wish to simplify or expand this expression.

Generally, you might think of subscripts as having higher precedence than superscripts in this context: $L_{\mu}^n$ means $(L_{\mu})^n$. You can also think about this as if $\mu$ were variable; if we define
$$f(x)=\mu x(1-x)$$
your usual method for calculating $f^2(x)$ would work. The notation $L_{\mu}$ merely gives a name to the family of functions of this form one could get for various $\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

We are given that $\,L_\mu(x) := \mu x(1-x).\,$
We have that
$$ x_1 := L_\mu(x) = \mu x(1-x), \tag{1}$$
$$ x_2 := L_\mu(x_1) = \mu x_1(1-x_1), \tag{2} $$
$$ x_3 := L_\mu(x_2) = \mu x_2(1-x_2) \tag{3} $$
are the first three iterates.
Substitute $\,x_2\,$ from equation $(2)$
to get
$$ x_3 = \mu  (\mu x_1(1-x_1)) (1-\mu x_1(1-x_1)). \tag{4}$$
Substitute $\,x_1\,$ from equation $(1)$ into this to get
$$ x_3 = \mu (\mu (\mu x(1-x))(1-\mu x(1-x))\\
 (1- \mu (\mu x(1-x))(1-(\mu x(1-x)))). \tag{5}$$
Expand $\,x_3\,$ into a polynomial in $\,x\,$ to get
$$ x_3 = \mu^3 x - (\mu^3+\mu^4+\mu^5)x^2 +\cdots + 4\mu^7 x^7 - \mu^7 x^8. \tag{6} $$